# All except closest

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="trigger">Click</a>
    <div class="inner">one</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="trigger">Click</a>
    <div class="inner">two</div>
</div>

$('.trigger').click(function () {
    $(".container :not:closest").find('.inner').slideUp('fast');
});
```

On click, I want ALL the `inner` divs to be slided up except the "closest" one, the parent of the `trigger` that was just clicked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like so:

```
$(".container").not($(this).closest('.container'))
```

Or if the `.container`'s are all siblings:

```
$(this).closest('.container').siblings('.container')
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative:

```
var $i = $(".container .inner");

$('.trigger').click(function() {
    $i.not(this.nextElementSibling).slideUp('fast');
});
```